# How to measure accuracy in Langchain + OpenAI project

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, large-language-model

We created something similar to internal chatbot, where we processed a lot of internal documents. We have testing dataset with question and correct answer. Right now we are focusing on better accurancy and we are trying to find a way how to compare output from bot against correct answer in dataset.

Manual review, which is time consuming.